# How to divide rows in new column by first / previous row?

Tags: r, rows, divide

I would like to create two columns:

1. That the value from the next row should be divided by the value in the first row.
2. In order for the value from the next row to be divided by the value from the previous line and expressed as a percentage.

Data

```
No    Value
1    10
2    15
3    5
4    10
5    40
```

Result:

1.

```
No    Value    V2
1    10    1
2    15    1,5
3    5     0,5
4    10    1
5    40    4
```

2.

```
No    Value    V2    V4
1    10    1    100%
2    15    1,5    150%
3    5     0,5    33,33%
4    10    1    200%
5    40    4    400%
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(V2 = Value/first(Value), 
      V4 = 100 * Value/lag(Value, default = first(Value)) )
#No Value  V2        V4
#1  1    10 1.0 100.00000
#2  2    15 1.5 150.00000
#3  3     5 0.5  33.33333
#4  4    10 1.0 200.00000
#5  5    40 4.0 400.00000
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cbind(df1,
      with(df1, {
          data.frame(V2 = Value/Value[1],
                     V4 = 100* c(1, tail(Value, -1)/head(Value, -1)))
      }))
#  No Value  V2        V4
#1  1    10 1.0 100.00000
#2  2    15 1.5 150.00000
#3  3     5 0.5  33.33333
#4  4    10 1.0 200.00000
#5  5    40 4.0 400.00000
```

Answer (score 1):

Using libraries `dplyr` and `scales`,

```
data %>%
  mutate(V2 = Value / first(Value),
         V4 = scales::percent(Value / lag(Value)))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
     No Value    V2 V4   
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1    10   1   NA%  
2     2    15   1.5 150% 
3     3     5   0.5 33%  
4     4    10   1   200% 
5     5    40   4   400%
```